# I want to delete Linux Ubuntu from my computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have two storage devices on my computer:

1. **C:** SSD 500gb with Windows 10 on it.
2. **D:** HDD 1TB with Linux Ubuntu on it.

I want to delete Linux from the D: drive while keeping the rest of the data on that drive. How can I do that?

Comment: One way is to get a 1 TB USB drive, copy the data onto it as a backup.  Then format the 1 TB drive in the computer and restore the data

Comment: Is "rest of the data on that drive" on a Linux system partition? Is `D:` really the drive? Linux needs a filesystem with certain features, it cannot work on NTFS; and AFAIK Windows 10 does not understand, i.e. cannot assign a drive letter to such filesystem. So most likely your Linux occupies some partition(s) on the HDD and `D:` is yet another partition. So you don't "delete Linux from D:"; you probably can delete the Linux partition(s) and keep `D:`; and then think if and how to use the free space after Linux. But to tell for sure we need to see the partition layout (e.g. `diskmgmt.msc`).

Comment: You are unlikely to be able to read the Ubuntu partition from Windows without doing additional legwork. If you just want to boot straight into Windows without seeing the GRUB / Linux bootloader, you might be better adjusting your BIOS settings to select the Windows disc as the boot drive.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Answer (score -1):

Is this data on the Linux D partition?

If it is, it's probably in ext4 format that is not supported by Windows
and you need to boot Linux in order to save it before removing this
partition.

Once you don't need D any more, you may delete it using any third-party
partition editor. However, you need to be sure that it's not essential
to the boot process, so do the following first.

Before touching D,
[Run a Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).
This should remove the dual-boot with Linux and reinstate the Windows
boot loader. Keep the boot disk handy, just in case.

Now you may remove D by formatting it.

I would suggest, in order to be safe, to take an image backup of your
entire disk.
A product that I like is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html)
(but others exist).
I also suggest to
[Create AOMEI Bootable CD/DVD/USB Based on Windows PE](https://www.ubackup.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html)
to be able to recover from a disastrous error and return the disk image.

Comment: Why downvote ???